# I have a simple to do app made in angular, how would I go about saving the items pushed to the array to localstorage?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple todo app that pushes items to an array, the array has some harcoded examples here just as a sanity check, my issue is getting the items to save to localstorage, most of the research i have done involves the use of a variable and I am not sure how to implement this.

```
// todo controller
    MyApp.controller('todoController', ['$scope', function($scope){
       // array that will hold all todo list items
      $scope.items = [
        // hard coded list items for sanity check
        {title: 'Pet Kitteh', status: ''}, 
        {title: 'Appreciate Lolcats', status: ''},
      ];

      $scope.submitNewItem = function() {
        if( $scope.newItem ) {
          $scope.items.push({title: $scope.newItem});
          $scope.newItem = '';
        }
      };

      $scope.completeItem = function(index) {
        if( $scope.items[index].status == 'completed' ) {
          $scope.items[index].status = '';
        } else {
          $scope.items[index].status = 'completed';
        }
      };`enter code here`

      $scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: didnt get what do you mean by saving it in a local storage... Is it a web application?

Comment: Yes a simple web application thanks. I have tried various methods to no avail such as $window.localStorage.setItem(key,value). To be a little clearer the items appear in a dynamic list that clears on page refresh, I would like the added items to save so upon pge refresh the added items remain.

Comment: to no avail, meaning they threw an error, or just did nothing. would help if you provided such various methods so it at least looks like you did your homework before asking. It would also prevent us from suggesting solutions that you've already tried.

Comment: My recommendation is to try using ngStorage module for this rather than native JS methods. It's super simple. Check it out on GitHub.

Comment: I have checked a lot of articles here on stackoverflow, in regards to homework I have been at this roughly 2 hours now and have tried methods such as localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify($scope.items));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Angular you should be looking into [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

Just make sure you have ngStorage installed and injected into your application.

Then you can inject `$localStorage` into your controller and go with:

```
 $localStorage.items = $scope.items;
```

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing me in the right direction, onwards and upwards :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use $window.localStorage.myKey = "string value";

Also verify that you've injected $window at the top.

MyApp.controller('todoController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){

Comment: Why am I being downvoted for answering the question?

Comment: I doubt *"for answering the question"* is the reason for the downvote.

Comment: What is the reason then? @KevinB

Comment: Would have to ask the downvoter. Or you could just mouseover the downvote button

Comment: @KevinB message received

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions and help, will have a look into all the methods described :)